# Indian citizen with valid H1-B visa until 11/2020. Do I need to apply for Schengen visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, spain, h1b-visas

I am opening up this thread to know from fellow travelers who are planning to visit tje EU (Spain in particular) from the US. I plan to travel somewhere in December 2018 around Christmas time, go to India after staying there for 7-10 days, and return to the US by the 4th week of January.

Do I need to apply for a Schengen visa in advance, or can I get visa on arrival as I am a valid US non permanent resident? Also, I do not have an H-1B visa stamped in my passport, but I have an approved I-797A (Notice of H-1B visa approval).

Please let me know if something is not clear from my end, looking forward to hearing.

Thanks.

Comment: Without an H-1B visa in your passport, you will be unable to return to the US.  You will need to get one while you are in Europe or India.

Comment: @phoog thank for letting me know. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a visa in advance.

US visas can get you out of airside transit visa requirements but they don't help you for a visit or a landside transit in the Schengen area.

The Schengen area only does visa on arrival in very limited circumstances, mostly EU citizen's family, seamen and emergencies. They aren't available to regular travelers in normal circumstances.

Comment: Having a H1-B visa will be in your favour of getting a Schengen visa though as you are unlikely to illegally emigrate from the USA to the Schengen area.